# Top Slide Menu without plugin using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hi I am creating a top slide menu using Jquery and Css. As i click on the button the menu should appear on the top of the screen, and If i click on the button or any where in the window it should get close.

I am unable to get the nav bar, some thing is going wrong with my code. Here is the code what I have tried.

HTML:

```
<body class="cbp-spmenu-push">
    <nav class="cbp-spmenu cbp-spmenu-horizontal cbp-spmenu-top" id="cbp-spmenu-s3">
        <h3>Menu</h3>
        <a href="#">Celery seakale</a> 
        <a href="#">Dulse daikon</a> 
        <a href="#">Zucchini garlic</a> 
        <a href="#">Catsear azuki bean</a> 
        <a href="#">Dandelion bunya</a> 
        <a href="#">Rutabaga</a> 
        <a href="#">Celery seakale</a> 
        <a href="#">Dulse daikon</a> 
        <a href="#">Zucchini garlic</a>
        <a href="#">Catsear azuki bean</a> 
        <a href="#">Dandelion bunya</a> 
        <a href="#">Rutabaga</a>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="main">
            <section>
                <button id="showTop" style="margin-top:300px;">Show/Hide Top Slide Menu</button>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#showTop').click(function() {
    debugger;
    $('#cbp-spmenu-s3').toggle();
    $('#cbp-spmenu-s3').toggleClass('active');
});
});
```

Css:

```
.cbp-spmenu-horizontal {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.cbp-spmenu-horizontal a {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    padding: 0.8em;
    border-left: 1px solid #258ecd;
}
.cbp-spmenu,
.cbp-spmenu-push {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.cbp-spmenu-top {
    top: -150px;
    display:none;
}
.cbp-spmenu-top.cbp-spmenu-open {
    top: 0px;
}
```

demo Link:
[Demo Code Link](http://jsfiddle.net/rC8Sk/1/)

Comment: lol after 5 minutes of messing with : http://jsfiddle.net/rC8Sk/1/ I realized the jquery has not loaded yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code can help you as per your requirement. Slide toggle the menu and hide if you click any where on the document too.

```
$('#showTop').on('click',function(){
            $('.cbp-spmenu-top').slideToggle('slow')
            .toggleClass('active'); // if you wish to add/romove class
        });
        $('#showTop, .cbp-spmenu-top').on('click',function(event){
            event.stopPropagation(); // Stop propogation on selected element
        });
        $(document).on('click',function(){
            $('.cbp-spmenu-top').slideUp('slow'); // hide menu if you click anywhere in the document
        });
```

Update working example :[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/rC8Sk/16/)

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

Had a look again and i noticed there is a fixed height applied to the nav, well you could possibly loosen it up.

The idea is to figure out nav's height via jquery and use that value as the `top` property.

Heres a quick way of going about it ( would need some refactoring )

```
var $nav = $(".cbp-spmenu");
var $navBtn = $("#showTop");
var navHeight = $nav.height() + "px";
var navTop = "-" + navHeight;
//$('.cbp-spmenu-top').hide();

$nav.css({top: navTop});

$navBtn.on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ( !$nav.hasClass("active") ) {
        $nav.addClass("active");
        $nav.removeAttr("style");
    } else {
        $nav.removeClass("active");
        $nav.css({top: navTop});        
    }
});
```

**Updated fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/Varinder/rC8Sk/15/

Well, there are few things goin on:

I'll try to touch on all of them:

Nav would probably need `absolute` positioning in order to correctly implement `top` position values.

```
.cbp-spmenu-horizontal {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    overflow: hidden;
    position:absolute;
}
```

jQuery's `.show()` and `.hide()` methods work by toggling inlined `display` properties which will complicate transitions ( infact, i dont think its possible to transition from `display:none` to `display:block`)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //$('.cbp-spmenu-top').hide();
    $('#showTop').click(function() {
    $('.cbp-spmenu-top').toggleClass('cbp-spmenu-open');//.show();
});
});
```

Further amendments to css leads to this working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/Varinder/rC8Sk/7/

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
$('.cbp-spmenu-top').hide();
$('#showTop').click(function() {
    $('.cbp-spmenu-top').toggle();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rC8Sk/8/

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/
Display or hide the matched elements.

Or even better for effect...

```
$('.cbp-spmenu-top').hide();
$('#showTop').click(function() {
    $('.cbp-spmenu-top').slideToggle();
});
```

You do need to get rid of some of the style rules though. You dont need the transition rules as jQuery will do this.

http://jsfiddle.net/rC8Sk/14/ (updated CSS)

https://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/ Display or hide the matched elements with a sliding motion.

Comment: although slideToggle will work but as i understand it - slideToggle will manipluate ```height``` value from 0 to ..something.. whereas the nav is positioned absolutely in order to do manipluations on ```top``` css property which will give it a more "sliding drawer" sort of effect via css transitions

Comment: Hence the mention of getting rid of some style rules as per http://jsfiddle.net/rC8Sk/14/

Comment: Oh true, sorry my bad. I was trying to hint that although jQuery can handle animations, the effect will not look quiet similar to css transitions which were there. You could go about using jQuerys animate method to acheive it but because the styles to implement it were already there - why not use it? :)

Answer (score 1):

Try Dis: [working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rC8Sk/11/) and import following scripts in your html form:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.maskedinput.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

jquery:

```
$('.cbp-spmenu-top').hide();
$('#showTop').click(function() {
$('.cbp-spmenu-top').toggle();
});
```